# React: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined with an API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple list in React where I'm fetching data from an array, and it's working.
But now that I want to fetch data from an external API, I have the following error

```
Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

I tried replacing `.data` with `.json()` but didn't work.

https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-taussig-e3vy7?file=/src/App.js:561-571

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";
import axios from "axios";

export default () => {
  const initialList = [
    {
      id: "1",
      name: "John"
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      name: "Doe"
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      name: "Seb"
    }
  ];

  const [list, setList] = React.useState([]);
  const [name, setName] = React.useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/")
      .then((response) => {
        setList(response.data.list);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);

  function handleChange(event) {
    setName(event.target.value);
  }

  function handleAdd() {
    const newList = list.concat({ name });
    setList(newList);
    setName("");
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" value={name} onChange={handleChange} />
        <button type="button" onClick={handleAdd}>
          Add
        </button>{" "}
      </div>

      <ul>
        <div>
          {list.map((item, index) => (
            <li key={item.id}>
              <div>{item.name}</div>
            </li>
          ))}
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I just ran you Sandbox, there is no list Object in your API response. Just use `setList(response.data)`

Comment: @Tushar You are right. Still learning React, why do I need `Object` exactly ?

Comment: Your response from API is a JSON. `response.data.list` does not exists, which is undefined and thats why you had the error. In future, just have `console.log(response)` after you API calls to check the response object. Hope that helped

Comment: @Tushar Understood. Thank you!

Comment: Your usage of concat is wrong: `const newList = list.concat({ name });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of your API doesn't have `data.list`

Try instead:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/")
      .then((response) => {
        setList(Object.values(response.data));
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);
```

Comment: Working perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: @AlyaKra If this answer correctly answered your question, please select it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Issue is with the way you are processing the response from the XHR call. The data returned by the URL `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/` is an array. There is no element called `list` in the data. So when you do `response.data.list`, the list variable gets set to `undefined`.

PFB revised code
https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-tdd-xjw6z

```
...
 axios
      .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/")
      .then((response) => {
        setList(response.data); //Change here
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);
...
```

Comment: the list variable gets set to `undefined`, not null. NULL and Undefined are very different in JS

Comment: @Tushar thanks for pointing it out. I have corrected the answer